# How does etcd guarantee order of sent messages?

Tags: etcd, raft

I don't seem to find out how etcd guarantees that messages sent by the same (follower) node will be received in order. The `message` struct does not seem to include a 'sent index', e.g., for `MSGProp` which does not even include the term.

On the same note, what if a message is delayed? Is there a timestamp after which the message is dropped?

Comment: Is there any requirement that they _are_ sent in order? I don't know the details of etcd specifically, but in general consensus algorithms must sent idempotent messages over an asynchronous network, so they can't rely on ordering nor timing, and don't need to.

Comment: Etcd is a KV store, if a node wants to (say) `read x` followed by `write x` the order clearly matters. But it might be the case that they don't offer this guarantee, outside of using tcp. I just want to make sure.

Comment: That is true, but note that if a client reads strictly after another one writes, _that_ is your message order. That is, the leader will receive each request serially and process them as such. Raft itself is agnostic to message ordering. (I realize I'm not really answering your question, hence the comments.As an exercise, though, prodding through Raft at a high level may help answer your question, especially with respect to reordering and delays.)

Comment: Understood, thanks! But just to clarify, I meant `read x` and `write x` issued from the _same_ node being reordered. It seems easy enough to detect, yet AFAIK this is not done in etcd.

Comment: In that case it is even easier. :) Since the same node is making the requests, and Raft is linearizable, the client is guaranteed to read the write it made (or something newer). I think what you're looking for is the `term`, `logTerm`, and `index` fields in the proto message, which act as a sequence number of sorts.